# Brezis Functional Analysis Exercise 8.35 - About Differential Equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE:
$$(1)\begin{cases}
-u''+au'+bu=f\text{ on }(0,1)\\
u(0)=u(1)=0
\end{cases}$$
where $f\in L^2$ and $a,b\in C([0,1])$. We know that when $a=b=0$, (1) has a unique solution in $H^2(0,1)$. Thus, we can define an operator $S:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow H^2(0,1)$ such that $Sf$ is just the unique solution of (1) when $a=b=0$. It is then easy to see that problem (1) is equivalent to
$$(2)\begin{cases}
u\in H^1(0,1)\\
u=S(f-au'-bu)
\end{cases}$$
Define $T:H^1(0,1)\rightarrow H^1(0,1), Tu=-S(au'+bu)$. I showed that $T$ is a bounded operator from $H^1$ to $H^2$. By Sobolev embedding theorem, $T$ is thus a compact operator from $H^1$ to itself. I then want to use the Fredholm Alternative to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition 1:** (1) has a solution for every $f\in L^2(0,1)$ iff (1) only has the zero solution when $f=0$.

Since (1) only has the zero solution when $f=0$ iff $I-T$ is injective iff $I-T$ is surjective (by the Fredholm Alternative), it suffices to show that $I-T$ is surjective iff (1) has a solution for every $f\in L^2(0,1)$. The forward direction is easy (for every $f\in L^2$, there exists $u\in H^1$ such that $u-Tu=Sf$), but I am not sure how to deal with the other direction. I also want to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition 2:** The space of solutions of (1) with $f=0$ has dimension 0 or 1. If this dimension is 1, then problem (1) has a solution iff $\int_0^1f\phi_0=0$ for some nonzero $\phi_0$ to be determined.

The hint on the book is to use Exercise 8.33 (which is about the simplicity of eigenvalues of a 1D Sturm-Liouville operator with zero Dirichlet condition) and the Fredholm Alternative. I don't know how to use the hint because we don't have the first order term $au'$ in a Sturm-Liouville operator. Besides, it seems like that I need to guess what $\phi_0$ is. I tried to use the unique solution of (1) for $f=0$ as my $\phi_0$, but I did not obtain any useful information. I am welcome any hints and comments.

Comment: Sturm Liouville operators do have a first order term.  Generally, if you compute $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ p(x) u' \right]$, you'll get a first order term involving $u'$.